# CRC32 and polynomial division in Java using byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, crc32

I am having trouble with understanding how byte array behave and how to do crc32 algorithm on it.

So i must make crc32 update(byte []b,int off,int len) method, im confused when it comes to shifting and aplaying xor on array with poly. how????
I know that you must do shifting but its an array and every byte behave like its have no connection with others bytes in array. I thought that if i shift  right for one or smth it will move whole array right,it will be so much easier. 
And also ,why when I use b[0]=(byte)(b[0]^0xff) gives me good result but first 24 bits are 1???

If you have any idea how to do it, or have some information that will clear this problem ,thank you.

Comment: It is always a good idea to share the code of what you have done.

Comment: Most practical CRC implementations work on byte level (using lookup tables) to avoid the costly bit shift operations.

Comment: It looks like you have a ways to go to understand how CRCs work and are computed. I recommend that you spend some quality time with [this tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt), and then come back if you still have questions.